# Hierarchical query without a start with clause

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy, mybatis, hierarchical-data

I am working on a db schema with hierarchical data. Lets say the schema is like the following -

```
ID1     parent_ID1    ID2      ID3
```

where ID1 parent_ID1 have the hierarchy information. The table is indexed on ID1 and ID2.

Now, I want to retrieve records in hierarchical way such that all the records have ID3 = someValue

I am thinking about the following query -

```
Select *
from table
where ID3 = somevalue
connect by prior ID1 = parent_ID1
```

I also have ID2 corresponding to ID3 = somevalue. But I do not know the root rows for the query.

Now, how much the efficiency would be impacted if I include or do not include ID2 in where clause. And how costly the query would be without a START WITH clause. I have read that in this case, oracle with treat each row as the root row and then connect accordingly. But I wanted to have a better understanding of the use case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What kind of result you want to see?